# Display buttons dynamically in android but once the buttons are added to layout they are coming in each of them

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, chatbot

[Screenshot for first message and and how buttons are coming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRAJu.png)
[Screenshot of second message and how buttons shifted down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7AhN.png)

I am developing a chat android app with a
chatbot client,i want to display two buttons in a layout which i am
inflating in my main activity as everytime a new message comes in. If
it is sent by user then right side if by bot then left side. As i am
adding buttons to that layout where condition occurs to set those
buttons then they are coming in any message of that layout either it
is user or bot. As we type new message its like buttons come down or
they are coming in 2nd latest message.

Buttons code:

ChatActivity.java file :

```
if (btnname.contentEquals("Lync")) {
                                    LinearLayout vgjp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.m123);

                                    Button btn1=(Button) new Button(this);
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


                                    btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
                                    Button btn2=(Button) new Button(this);
                                    btn2.setLayoutParams(params);


                                    btn1.setText(btnname);
                                    btn2.setText("Other App");

                                    vgjp.addView(btn1);
                                    vgjp.addView(btn2);

                                    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            // Perform action on click
                                            sendMessageToBot("Lync");

                                        }
                                    });
                                    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            // Perform action on click
                                            sendMessageToBot("Other App");
                                        }
                                    });

                                } else if (btnname.contentEquals("Outlook")) {



                                    LinearLayout vgjp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.m123);

                                    Button btn1=(Button) new Button(context);
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                                    btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
                                    Button btn2=(Button) new Button(context);
                                    btn2.setLayoutParams(params);


                                    btn1.setText(btnname);
                                    btn2.setText("Other App");

                                    vgjp.addView(btn1);
                                    vgjp.addView(btn2);
                          btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            // Perform action on click
                                            sendMessageToBot("Outlook");
                                        }
                                    });
                          btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            // Perform action on click
                                            sendMessageToBot("Other App");
                                        }
                                    });


                                }

                            }
```

This layout in this xml file is inflated as any text is received either from bot or from user :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/newid">




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/in_message_bg"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:maxWidth="240dp" />

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/myVideo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
     <!-- This code is for Buttons -->
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/m123">

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    This is my main container layout xml file :

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

 `enter code here`tools:context="com.directlineex.brsingh.directlineandroidexample.ChatActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/images"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/mikebutton"

            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mikebutton"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chatSendButton"
            android:hint="Type Query" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/chatSendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/background_floating_material_dark"
            android:text="Send MSG"
            android:textColor="@color/background_material_light"/>



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/messagesContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/messageEdit"
            android:layout_below="@+id/meLbl"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:divider="@null" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/meLbl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="MySelf"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friendLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:text="Friend"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

ChatAdapter.java Adapter file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.directlineex.brsingh.directlineandroidexample.ChatActivity;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;


public class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private String localToken = "";
private String conversationId = "";
private String primaryToken = "";
private String botName = "";
private final List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
private Activity context;




public ChatAdapter(Activity context, List<ChatMessage> chatMessages) {
    this.context = context;
    this.chatMessages = chatMessages;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (chatMessages != null) {
        return chatMessages.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public ChatMessage getItem(int position) {
    if (chatMessages != null) {
        return chatMessages.get(position);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    final ChatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_message, null);
        holder = createViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // holder = createViewHolder(convertView);
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();



    }


    boolean myMsg = chatMessage.getIsme() ;
 setAlignment(holder, myMsg);
holder.txtMessage.setText(chatMessage.getMessage()); //Make a temporary 
variable here for this

    // if(chatMessage.getDate()!=null)
    holder.txtInfo.setText(chatMessage.getDate());

    chatMessage.setB1(null);
    chatMessage.setB2(null);

    return convertView;
}





public void add(ChatMessage message) {

    chatMessages.add(message);

}

public void add(List<ChatMessage> messages) {
    chatMessages.addAll(messages);
}
public void setAlignment(ViewHolder holder,boolean mymsg){

    if (!mymsg) {


holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.in_message_bg);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
      /*  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams12 =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.temp.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.temp.setLayoutParams(layoutParams12);*/
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.content.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);

        layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.txtInfo.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        holder.txtInfo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        //holder.btn1=(Button) new Button(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        holder.btn1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        holder. btn1.setLayoutParams(params);






    } else {



holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.out_message_bg);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

        holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.content.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);
        layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.txtInfo.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        holder.txtInfo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    }
}


private ViewHolder createViewHolder(View v) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
  /*  holder.btn1=new Button(context);
    holder.btn2=new Button(context);*/
    holder.txtMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

    holder.content = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.content);
    // holder.btn1=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    //holder.btn2=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    // holder.lyncbtn=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.lyncbtn);
    //(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.contentWithBackground);

    holder.contentWithBG = (LinearLayout) 
v.findViewById(R.id.contentWithBackground);
    holder.txtInfo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
    // holder.temp=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.m123);

    holder.btn1=(Button) new Button(context);
    holder.btn2=(Button) new Button(context);
    return holder;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtMessage;
    public TextView txtInfo;
    public Button btn1;
     public Button btn2;
    //public Button lyncbtn;
    public LinearLayout content;
    public LinearLayout contentWithBG;
    // public LinearLayout temp;

}
}
```

Comment: Add some screen shots and your code while posting a question.

Comment: @AldrinMathew added all the things, you can now go through it and see if i can get any help.That would be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Chatting messages should be added in recycler view**

> Firstly take a recycler view on your chat activity. And make adapter for it.
>
> In adapter pass list of messages.
>
> Now take two layout in row of recycler view one for to user and one for from user(one is left align and one right align) and Visibility of both layout is GONE by default.
>
> When new message come to you than add it to list of messages and set it left side of layout which is for message box. And make it visible and notify adapter by notifyDataSetChanged.
>
> When new message sent by you than add it to list of messages and set it to right side of layout which is for message box. And make it visible and notify adapter by notifyDataSetChanged.

It may help you, if any query then please comment me.

Comment: hey chetan, thanks for the info but can you now go through the code and screenshots and see if you could help me more precisely by looking through the problem.

Comment: Pls send me code of your list adapter of messages. So i can help you better.

Comment: Added the adapter. Check it please